# Scroll Mdi Child Form on Object Move like Pan window in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a Pan window application in this application when I have a window with transparent object when I moved this object at the same time mdi scroll will also scroll as per this below image. This image is an example of my current application. https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpkBn.jpg

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class MDI : Form
    {
        private int childFormNumber = 0;
        public Form1 objfrmPalm;
        public Form1 objMain;
        public MDI()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.HorizontalScroll.Minimum = 0;
            this.VerticalScroll.Maximum = 2000;
        }

        private void ShowNewForm(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form childForm = new Form();
            childForm.MdiParent = this;
            childForm.Text = "Window " + childFormNumber++;
            childForm.Show();
        }

        private void OpenFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            openFileDialog.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string FileName = openFileDialog.FileName;
            }
        }

        private void SaveAsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveFileDialog.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            saveFileDialog.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
            if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string FileName = saveFileDialog.FileName;
            }
        }

        private void ExitToolsStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void CutToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void CopyToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void PasteToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void ToolBarToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            toolStrip.Visible = toolBarToolStripMenuItem.Checked;
        }

        private void StatusBarToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            statusStrip.Visible = statusBarToolStripMenuItem.Checked;
        }

        private void CascadeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LayoutMdi(MdiLayout.Cascade);
        }

        private void TileVerticalToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LayoutMdi(MdiLayout.TileVertical);
        }

        private void TileHorizontalToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LayoutMdi(MdiLayout.TileHorizontal);
        }

        private void ArrangeIconsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LayoutMdi(MdiLayout.ArrangeIcons);
        }

        private void CloseAllToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (Form childForm in MdiChildren)
            {
                childForm.Close();
            }
        }

        private void MDI_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        #region mnufrmPage_Click
        private void mnufrmPage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            objMain = new Form1();
            objMain.MdiParent = this;
            objMain.Show(); 

        }
        #endregion 

        #region mnuPalmWindow_Click
        private void mnuPalmWindow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            objfrmPalm = new Form1();
            objfrmPalm.MdiParent = this;
            objfrmPalm.Size = new Size(369, 335);
            objfrmPalm.l1 = new Label();
            objfrmPalm.l1.AutoSize = false;
            objfrmPalm.l1.Size = new Size(140, 73);
            objfrmPalm.l1.Text = "";
            objfrmPalm.l1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            //objfrmPalm.l1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            //objfrmPalm.Controls.Add(l1);
            objfrmPalm.l1.Parent = objfrmPalm.pictureBox1;
            objfrmPalm.pictureBox1.Controls.Add(objfrmPalm.l1);
            objfrmPalm.l1.MouseMove += l1_MouseMove;
            objfrmPalm.l1.MouseDown += l1_MouseDown;
            objfrmPalm.l1.Paint += L1_Paint;
            objfrmPalm.Show(); 

            //frmPalmWindow objpalm = new frmPalmWindow();
            //objpalm.MdiParent = this;
            //objpalm.Show();
        }

        private void L1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Red), new Rectangle(0, 0, ((Label)sender).Width - 1, ((Label)sender).Height - 1));


        }

        void l1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                objfrmPalm.MouseDownLocation = e.Location;


            }

        }

        void l1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                objfrmPalm.l1.Left = e.X + objfrmPalm.l1.Left - objfrmPalm. MouseDownLocation.X;
                objfrmPalm.l1.Top = e.Y + objfrmPalm.l1.Top - objfrmPalm.MouseDownLocation.Y;

                objMain.AutoScroll = true;
                objMain.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(Cursor.Position.X + e.X, Cursor.Position.Y + e.Y);
                // this.Refresh();
                //this.SetAutoScrollMargin(e.X, e.Y);

                //myControl.SetDisplayRectLocation(
                //myControl.DisplayRectangle.X,
                //myControl.DisplayRectangle.Y + MouseWheelDelta * ScrollAmount  );



                //this.HorizontalScroll.Value = e.Y;
                //this.VerticalScroll.Value = e.X;

                // Point CurrentPoint; 
                // this.SetAutoScrollMargin(e.X, e.Y);
                //this.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(Convert.ToInt32( Math.Abs(this.AutoScrollPosition.X)),Convert.ToInt32( Math.Abs(CurrentPoint.Y)));

                //this.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(Convert.ToInt32(e.X + objfrmPalm.l1.Left - objfrmPalm.MouseDownLocation.X+100), Convert.ToInt32(e.Y + objfrmPalm.l1.Top - objfrmPalm.MouseDownLocation.Y+200));

                //this.Refresh();
            }


        }
        #endregion 
        private Point MouseDownLocation;
        private void label1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
            {
               // label1.Left = e.X + label1.Left - MouseDownLocation.X;
               // label1.Top = e.Y + label1.Top - MouseDownLocation.Y;



               //// this.ScrollToControl(label1);

               // this.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(Convert.ToInt32(e.X + label1.Left - this.MouseDownLocation.X + 100), Convert.ToInt32(e.Y + label1.Top - this.MouseDownLocation.Y + 200));

               // this.Refresh();
            }
        }

        private void label1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            //if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
            //{
            //    MouseDownLocation = e.Location;
            //}
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me and if I missed something then please guide me.